# Clojure quot and rem functions

Tags: clojure

I'm new to clojure and messing around in the repl.

I've noticed that I'm getting expected results with the rem function.

So without clojure if I do 8/5 = 1.6

```
user=> (quot 8 5)
1
```

as expected

```
user=> (rem 8 5)
3
```

Why am I getting 3? I was kind of expecting a 6.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you want for what you imagined rem to be:

```
(defn frac [x y] (let [r (rem x y)] (double (/ r y))))

user> (frac 8 5)
0.6
```

Answer (score 2):

[rem](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/rem) gives you the remainder of indeger division of 8 by 5 (since 8 = 5 * 1 + *3*)

So what you're getting is correct. Why would you expect 6 there?

Comment: It's late and I was expecting the mantissa instead of the remainder. I appreciate you clearing that up